# Acumatic End Point does not support REST

Tags: acumatica

I'm getting the following error when trying do a put to customer endpoint

"System contract version 1 for endpoint BI/100 does not support REST"

any idea what this error means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means precisely what it says: you are trying to perform REST operation against a Contract-based endpoint that does not support REST operations. Acumatica has a notion of "system contract version" (which can be seen on the Endpoint Properties page on Web Services Endpoint screen), and at this point only system contract version 2 supports REST operations.

There are two ways of getting system contract version 2 endpoint - either by extending an existing system contract version 2 endpoint, or by creating a brand new endpoint in the (recent version of) Acumatica. To expand on the latter, Acumatica always creates new endpoints with the latest available public system contract version (which is 2 at the moment).

Comment: Thanks ya the contract version was set to 1.